# Convert NSData object to NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c

I get response from my server in format like this:

```
[_postViolationOperation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
      if (responseObject != nil && [responseObject isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) {
            //some code to convert responseObject to NSArray
            //responseObject looks like this: ["fsdfsf","sdfsfd"]
      }

 } failure:nil];
```

How can I convert this to NSArray?

Comment: please share your code

Comment: can you provide some additional code , it is easy to resolve

Comment: Your question should be, 'How to parse JSON data into NSArray?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: responseData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
```

Comment: what is the purpose of this code?

Answer (score 2):

Here is code to Convert NSData object to NSArray

```
NSError *error = nil; //for error
NSData  *dataObject; //put your data in dataObject
NSArray *ArrayObject = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: dataObject options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &error];
```